Set RDP Ubuntu Desktop 24.04 resolution when no HDMI display attached
I just upgraded to 24.04, my PC didn't connect any display, no HDMI. But I'm planning to control it through RDP. How do I do it? Is this RDP client issue? or RDP server issue? or just display issue? I couldn't change resolution, it said 640*480. It's not clickable. I'm expecting full screen resolution.



Which RDP client are you using?

@user68186 Turns out it was just nvidia driver issue, I have solved it. Now I have problem, when I disconnect the HDMI, I couldn't connect to RDP. It's connected but it's not detecting the display.

It will be great if you answered your own question and accepted your answer as correct. That will help others.
